# Ipython notebook crash using rmagic extension

Tags: ipython, rpy2

I am trying to run the [rmagic functions extension](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/urls/raw.github.com/ipython/ipython/3607712653c66d63e0d7f13f073bde8c0f209ba8/docs/examples/notebooks/rmagic_extension.ipynb) example, but ipython crashes with console error message '\u used without hex digits in character string starting "c:\u". I suspect that this is an R error message caused by rmagic passing c:\path instead of c:\ or c:/.

There is probably an easy way to fix this (IPython or Notebook startup parameters?) , but, as a newbie to rmagic and rpy2, I need some expert help please.

The following simple snippet from the example causes the kernel to die:

```
import rpy2
%load_ext rmagic
%R x=1
```

I am a windows user...

Answer (score 2):

Found a solution to this ipython/windows problem [here](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/2533)

Answer (score 0):

I am a Windows user. I went to my IPython extention folder which for me is:  `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\IPython\extensions`
and opened `rmagic.py` for editing.  Found the line

```
self.r('png("%s/Rplots%%03d.png",%s)' % (tmpd, png_args))
```

and replaced it with the line:

```
self.r('png("%s/Rplots%%03d.png",%s, type="cairo")' % (tmpd.replace('\\', '/'), png_args))
```

The reason you do this is described [here](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/2533)
and [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pythonxy/xX3lZFkX23g)